# Is this the best practice when reading and writing huge txt files in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am using something to the attune of this but getting inconsistent results and I am wondering if the Output file is too large and causing data to be lost.
Code I am using:

```
import os

files = os.listdir()
OUTFILE = "Merged.txt"
with open(OUTFILE,'w') as out_file:
    for file in files:
        with open(file,'r') as in_file:
            for line in in_file:
                if "some text" in line:
                    out_file.write(str(line))
```

for some reason I appear to be missing some lines that contain "some text" now I am currently working with around 200-400 GB of input files total each around 200,000-500,000KB each I am not sure if this is the best practice when working with an output file this large. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: The reason I ask Is it looks like I am missing some lines that contain "some text"

Comment: `if "some text" in in_file:` should be `if "some text" in line:`

Comment: The way your are handling files (which is generally correct with the exception of the typo) is already proper. By directly iterating over the files, Python can treat them as (buffered) streams – meaning it is only ever looking at a small portion of each file. The "200-400 GB" don't matter to Python in this way.

Comment: I was curious if the output file remains in memory until the iteration is complete ```for file in files``` or if it is just buffered however I think the way I am getting the files is causing issues through remote desktop

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The python script is correct just made a typo here